# Android getintent() method crashes

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an Android app with base API 11. I've been sending data between activities using intent and fetching data using getintent() getextras() all along. predominantly,I've been testing in API 23, i ran the same in api 15, it crashes.Even a simple getintent.hasextra also crashes. Is this a compatibility issue? i also added if getintent.getextras !=null but that didn't help me either. Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thank you

Code:
Activity 1:

```
 Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this,MFGroupDetailsScreen.class);
    detailIntent.putExtra("fromScreen",2);
    if(Constants.USER_ID==selectedGroup.groupOwner)
    {
        Group groupWithAllMembers=groupArray.get(0);
        for(Group group:groupArray)
        {
            if(group.groupID==Constants.GROUP_ID)
            {
                groupWithAllMembers = group;
                break;
            }
        }
        detailIntent.putExtra("members",groupWithAllMembers);
    }
    detailIntent.putExtra("selectedGroup",selectedGroup);
    startActivity(detailIntent);
```

here groupwithall members and selectedGroup are parceable

Activity 2:

```
         selectedGroup = (Group) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("selectedGroup");
```

Update:
Error stack trace

> 07-25 10:15:44.070: E/ingroupdetails(3391): Now in group details screen
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice/com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice.MFGroupDetailsScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice.MFGroupDetailsScreen.onCreate(MFGroupDetailsScreen.java:39)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   07-25 10:15:46.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3391):     ... 11 more
>   07-25 10:15:46.670: E/SurfaceFlinger(1129): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
>   07-25 10:15:50.710: E/InputDispatcher(1458): channel 'a6f1bc50 com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice/com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice.MFGroupListScreen (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   07-25 10:15:50.710: E/InputDispatcher(1458): channel 'a6bb8580 com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice/com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice.MFSocialScreen (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   07-25 10:15:50.710: E/InputDispatcher(1458): channel 'a6899430 com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice/com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice.DashboardScreen (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   07-25 10:15:50.740: E/Trace(3432): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>   07-25 10:15:50.750: E/jdwp(3432): Failed writing handshake bytes: Broken pipe (-1 of 14)
>   07-25 10:15:50.800: E/SurfaceFlinger(1129): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
>   07-25 10:15:50.800: E/InputDispatcher(1458): channel 'a732dea8 com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice/com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraphandlogservice.MFSocialScreen (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   07-25 10:15:50.840: E/SurfaceFlinger(1129): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
>   07-25 10:15:50.950: E/emuglGLESv2_enc(1793): a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute.
>   07-25 10:15:50.950: E/emuglGLESv2_enc(1793): [ 07-25 10:15:50.990  1458: 1473 D/         ]
>   07-25 10:15:50.950: E/emuglGLESv2_enc(1793): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9947680, tid 1473
>   07-25 10:15:51.370: E/emuglGLESv2_enc(1793): a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute.
>   07-25 10:18:55.930: E/GTalkService(1777): connectionClosed: no XMPPConnection - That's strange!

Comment: Can you add log with exception you have?

Comment: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class

Comment: Looks like you have conflict in the class implements Parcelable. Please share full log and your data class.

Comment: I have parceable object but i commented it out .Yet still the exception is thrown

Comment: that is the exception i am getting

Comment: can you open new activity without sending any data? If you can problem must be about what you send. Then please add code about what you send and how you send?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `putParcelable` and fetch it using `getParcelableExtra`.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("members",groupWithAllMembers);
bundle.putParcelable("selectedGroup",selectedGroup);
```

To fetch use -

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
bundle.getParcelable("members");
```

Comment: There is no putparcelable but only putparcelablearraylistextra. These are two objects not arraylist

Answer (score 0):

In your Group Class add following code:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Group createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Group(in);
        }

        public Group[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Group[size];
        }
    };
```

Above code will fix your error: `android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class`

If you have any other issue regarding `Parcelable` implementation, I would recommend to refer [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html)

Comment: Could you please update us with the stackTrace of the device that causes crash?

Comment: 4 WVGA( Nexus s) API  15 (Android 4.0.4,API 15)

Comment: a stack trace is appeared in Android Studio where we see errors and fix it accordingly. Please view https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html

Comment: Hi,i've updated with the error stack trace in my question thanks

Comment: An observation made was, it works fine till API 21. It begins to crash at API 19 and below

Comment: Please confirm is `MFGroupDetailsScreen.java` line no `39` is `selectedGroup = (Group) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("selectedGroup");`?

Comment: Also please check `selectedGroup = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("selectedGroup");` this works?? without type-casting

Comment: Guys, i got the solution. Public keyword was missing before static in Parcelable.creator. Thanks for the help